# Xpath - how to mark each element when finds two the same

Tags: selenium, xpath

Hi I have two exact element on the page I want to click first or second.When using [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2LMO.png) [0] two elements are marked[image]

what I tryed is '//span[contains(text(), "CTA Button")]' but both elements are marked
also '//span[contains(text(), "CTA Button")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2LMO.png)' again both are marked

[image: when using [1] to grab single argument]

```html
<div class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted">

  <!---->


  <!----><!---->
    <mat-slide-toggle class="mat-slide-toggle mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" id="mat-slide-toggle-6"><label class="mat-slide-toggle-label"><div class="mat-slide-toggle-bar"><input class="mat-slide-toggle-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="mat-slide-toggle-6-input" tabindex="0"><div class="mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><div class="mat-slide-toggle-thumb"></div><div class="mat-slide-toggle-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div></div></div><span class="mat-slide-toggle-content">
      CTA Button
    </span></label></mat-slide-toggle>
    <!---->
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *both elements are marked*?

Comment: Which Language You Are using Python or Other?

Comment: both elements are found when using '//span[contains(text(), "CTA Button")][1]'

Comment: Im using Python

Comment: @ranger : You have missed the `()` what OP suggested.That should work as per your screenshot. If you are looking for better answer then update the post with html in text format not screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to query first element: `(//span[contains(text(), "CTA Button")])[1]`

This is to query second element: `(//span[contains(text(), "CTA Button")])[2]`

Comment: no when using '//span[contains(text(), "CTA Button")][1]' both elements are found (2) [span.mat-slide-toggle-content, span.mat-slide-toggle-content]

Comment: In your example there is the only single `span` element. Xpath cannot return more than it exists in the structure.

Comment: @ranger you also should carefully use my advice. `//span[contains(text(), "CTA Button")][1]` is not the same as `(//span[contains(text(), "CTA Button")])[1]`.

Comment: yes but Im using the () just for debbuging the xpath in chrome browser that I could see what is going to be selected

Comment: These are different parentheses. In your case the test would look like `$x('(//span[contains(text(), "CTA Button")])[1]')`

Comment: Glad to know I managed to help you. You can mark my answer as correct.